Differences in Standardized Mean Difference (SMD) calculation between smd Package and manual calculation in R
I am trying to calculate the Standardized Mean Difference (SMD) between two groups in R and have encountered discrepancies between different methods of calculation.
While trying to calculate the SMD between two groups using gtsummary R package, I found this useful thread which allowed me to include SMD to my table. However, I noticed that the SMD for continuous variables calculated with gtsummary (together with smd function) is slightly different from that calculated using the CreateTableOne package. Trying to solve this issue, I have prepared a dummy example to compare the results when calculating SMD using the smd package versus manually calculating it:
library(smd)

# Generate random data
x <- rnorm(200)
g <- rep(1:2, each = 100)

# Split the data into two groups
x1 <- x[1:100]
x2 <- x[101:200]

# Calculate SMD using the smd package
smd_result <- smd(x, g)

# Manually calculate SMD using base R functions
manual_smd <- (mean(x1)-mean(x2))/sqrt((var(x1)+var(x2))/2)

# Output the results
smd_result
manual_smd

The smd package returned an SMD of approximately 0.004546278, while my manual calculation gives 0.004523489. I'd like to know if anyone has any idea of why this two results are slightly different?
I have also tried using various approaches such as Bias-corrected Standardized Mean Difference (Hedges' g), and the weighted pooled standard deviation, but I still cannot obtain the result given by the smd package.
Could anyone explain why there might be this discrepancy between the two methods? Are there inherent differences in the formulas used in the smd package compared to manual calculations?
I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Instead of using var() which computes the sample variance, compute and use the population variance (i.e., var2()) in your manual calculation.
set.seed(42)

library(smd)

# population variance
var2 <- function(x) {
  sum((x - mean(x))^2) / length(x)
}

# Generate random data
x <- rnorm(200)
g <- rep(1:2, each = 100)

# Split the data into two groups
x1 <- x[1:100]
x2 <- x[101:200]

# Output the results
data.frame(
  "smd_result" = smd(x, g)$estimate,
  "manual_result" = (mean(x1) - mean(x2)) / sqrt((var2(x1) + var2(x2)) / 2)
)
#>   smd_result manual_result
#> 1  0.1236725     0.1236725

Created on 2024-10-10 with reprex v2.1.1

Many thanks @the-mad-statter! Do you have any idea of why would smd function use population variance instead of sample variance? And is there any way of applying the sample variance when using this package?


I would presume population variance is used because the entire population is in hand, and therefore there is no need for an estimate of what the population variance might be based on a sample from the population. 2. I did not see a way to use the sample variance in smd().

